# Lightbulb matrix program with Python

Tags: python

I would like to ask for help with this task. How do you think I could write this program in Python? Thank you in advance for your assistance."

In a classroom, there is installed an n × n board, on which n^2 lightbulbs are placed. For each row and column of the board, there is a push button, which can change the state of the n lightbulbs in the corresponding row (or column) simultaneously to the opposite state. (Upon pressing the button, the lit bulbs in the respective row or column turn off, while the off ones turn on.) At the beginning of the break, all bulbs are in the off state. During the break, the students randomly push the buttons. How many button presses does the teacher need to restore the original state? (The buttons are single-state, meaning it's not visible whether they have been pressed or not.)

I would like to ask for help with this task. How do you think I could write this program in Python? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is for specific questions, so this is way too broad. Check out [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) for tips. (Even if this isn't homework per se, a lot of the same advice applies.) See also [ask].